# How to replace icon-font source with normal image source in CSS file

Tags: html, css

I want to replace the images with new ones but the problem is that the images are in font style.

Now I want to replace the following with normal image source, like

```
<img src="images/upload.png>
```

Below is the CSS file in which I want to make changes

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "fl-bigmug-line";
    src: url("../fonts/fl-bigmug-line.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/fl-bigmug-line.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../fonts/fl-bigmug-line.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/fl-bigmug-line.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("../fonts/fl-bigmug-line.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.fl-bigmug-line-ico,
[class^="fl-bigmug-line-"]:before, [class*=" fl-bigmug-line-"]:before,
[class^="fl-bigmug-line-"]:after, [class*=" fl-bigmug-line-"]:after {   
    font-family: 'fl-bigmug-line';
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

.fl-bigmug-line-add137:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
.fl-bigmug-line-add139:before {
    content: "\e001";
}
.fl-bigmug-line-add149:before {
    content: "\e002";
```

I tried to change the content like `content: url("images/upload.png");` but it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried simply using `content: url(.../images/upload.png)`? See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) for reference

Comment: i just tried but it's not working. @xs0

Comment: Can you please add what exactly you tried to the bottom of question?

Comment: i have added in the question @xs0

Comment: i again tried with the web url like "https://google.com/image.png" and this time it's working. But then why it's not working with local folder address.

Comment: What are the full paths of the CSS file and the image file? Perhaps you need some of those `../` ?

Comment: yes i see the answer, my point is if it's working fine with web url(htttp://google.com/images.png) then why not with local address(images/upload.png)

Comment: probably just the path is wrong somehow.. see my previous comment..

Comment: CSS full path is "mywebsite\css\fl-bigmug-line.css" and image path is "mywebsite\images\upload.png"

Comment: then this will probably work: `content: url("../images/upload.png")` or you can also go with `content: url("/images/upload.png")` ..

Comment: whoa!! now it's working when i try this "content: url("../images/upload.png")" but when i tried same with three dots "..." it didn't work. why ?

Comment: heh, I used `...` just as a placeholder, to be filled in by you :) On the other hand, `..` means "one directory up"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```css
.the-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.the-icon:before {
    content: url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3116de43059d7ea110181a5bb773bcdd?s=30");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <i class="the-icon"></i> Upload
</div>
```